# Get function parameters as dictionary

Tags: python

I know that there are a lot of questions/answers on *arg, **kwarg. However, I'm doing something a little backwards and couldn't find it addressed (perhaps I just don't know how to ask the question.) Anyway, I want to simplify the below:

```
def foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
     my_dict = dict(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg2)
     my_str = "{arg1} went up the {arg2} hill to fetch a pail of {arg3}".
               format(**my_dict)
```

note, I'd wrather not define foo as (self, **kwargs) as I like the autocomplete component of filling out the function.

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to create a dictionary from some parameters?

Comment: may be use `**locals()`?

Comment: @mshsayem - how about writing that up as an answer?

Comment: That requires some explanation, and I am really lazy ... :|

Comment: @mshsayem - its the answer  I would have posted, so I went ahead and did it.

Comment: @mshsayem - lazy or not, that would have gotten me there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are in the local namespace dict, so use it:

```
def foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
     my_str = "{arg1} went up the {arg2} hill to fetch a pail of {arg3}".
               format(**locals())
```

Answer (score 2):

`inspect` is what you are looking for:

```
import inspect

class T(object):
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
        my_dict = {arg: values[arg] for arg in args if arg != 'self'}
        my_str = "{arg1} went up the {arg2} hill to fetch a pail of {arg3}".format(**my_dict)
        print my_dict
        print my_str

z = T()
z.foo(3,4,5)
```

note the `arg != 'self'` part as this is a method call. If you have a function with a parameter `self` this will not display that parameter.

Comment: For my knowledge, is there a reason you chose inspect vs. locals()? Is there an advantage or pitfall that I need to be aware of.

Comment: @SteveJ Not really. The only difference is that locals will store other local variables as well. That is, you must call locals at the very beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As @dmg mentioned you can use `inspect`:

```
import inspect

def find_args(f):
    return inspect.getargspec(f)[0]

def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):
     my_args =  find_args(foo)
     my_dict = { k: v for k,v in zip(my_args, [arg1, arg2, arg3])}
     my_str = "{arg1} went up the {arg2} hill to fetch a pail of {arg3}".format(**my_dict)
     print my_str

foo('a','b', 'c')
```

Will return

```
a went up the b hill to fetch a pail of c
```